# React How to use a child component in a parent component

Tags: reactjs

This works in CodePen (it shows 'Test'):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return ( <h1> Test </h1> ) 
  }
}
/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

But when I try to encapsulate a Child component, it doesn't (it doesn't show anything).

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return 
    (
      <div>
        <h1> test </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Parent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return ( <Child /> ) 
  }
}
/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Could someone spot what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the console? It works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2174/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach, what bit you is [automatic semicolon insertion](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/08/26/javascript-semi-colon-insertion/). In your second example, in the `Child` component, there's a new line after `return`, which is interpreted as:

```
render() {
  return;  // implied semicolon - render returns nothing!
           // following lines are discarded. 
  (
  <div>
    <h1> test </h1>
  </div>
  );
}
```

So you just need to move the opening paren to be in the same line

```
class Child extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> test </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/70702/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove new line here

```
class Child extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> test </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```